# Drawing over image

Tags: c#

I'm trying to draw a rectangle over an image, the rectangle is drawn but the image disappears.

My code:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
currentBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
Bitmap temp1 = new Bitmap(currentBitmap.Height, currentBitmap.Width);

Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)temp1.Clone();
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmap);

Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);

gr.DrawRectangle(pen, 120, 120, 100, 100);

currentBitmap = (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();

pictureBox1.Image = currentBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Put your `Graphics` instance as well as your `Pen` instance inside a [`using` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) or you will get memory/resource leaks very soon.

Comment: You don't show any code that would explain the rectangle's disappearing. Which means it happens somewhere else. We need all relevant context!

Comment: Hi, thats all the code there is. This is attached to a button. currentBitmap is copied from a picturebox.

Comment: I edited my question with the code.

Comment: Most likely your pbox is too small and SizeMode is not Stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Put your drawing methods inside the pictureBox1 onPaint Method. Then you call that using

> pictureBox1.Paint += picturebox1_OnPaint;

Comment: Depending on the usecase, this could be a good options. But, if f.e. the image needs to be saved to disk (including the rectangle), this method will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this.
It was an error on my code which I didnt realize, i was just taking the width and height of the picturebox instead of the image data.

I changed

```
Bitmap temp1 = new Bitmap(currentBitmap.Height, currentBitmap.Width);
```

To

```
Bitmap temp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
```

Comment: This makes little sense but if it works for you, ok. I doubt this question, let alone the answers can be useful to anybody else. Imo it should be closed and/or deleted.

Comment: HI, i think you should try the code and check the result.

Answer (score -2):

This is likely due to the fact that your image is set in `pictureBox1`. Try making a new pictureBox to overlay the old one:

`pictureBox1` = image itself

`pictureBox2` = bitmap

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, doesnt work. New picturebox has a rectangle but no image. I tried something similar by setting the current picturebox null after cloning the image. Still the same result.

Comment: Would you mind editing in your entire code so I can have a look at it?

Comment: I've flagged your reply as unfriendly and unsupportive. Instead of saying this, you should elaborate.